# What is, exactly, a discrete group?

Tags: group-theory

What, exactly, is a discrete group?

In my understanding, a discrete group is a group $G$ on which the only topology 
that can be given is the discrete topology. For example, the group $S^1$ is not discrete because we can give it the topology inherited from $\mathbb C$.

Comment: There is no set on which the only topology that can be given is discrete.  You can always put the indiscrete topology as well.

Comment: @Joe, for the empty set and singletons the discrete topology and the indiscrete topology coincide.

Comment: @Ihf: Thanks.  I forgot about the trivial examples.

Comment: Often, "discrete" is used more to say "we don't care about the topology on this group", more than "we're going to put a specific topology on this group".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the setting in which the phrase would be used, $G$ is not simply a group, but a *topological group*.  A discrete group is a topological group in which the topology is discrete.

For example, let us look at the reals under addition, but equip the reals with the discrete topology.  This gives us a topological group, which by definition is discrete.

The fact that the reals **can** be equipped with a non-discrete topology (such as the usual one) which is compatible with addition is not relevant.

Comment: exactly my point

Answer (score 4):

"A discrete group is a group equipped with the discrete topology." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_group

If a set has more than one element then it can be given a non-discrete topology and so it does not make sense to require that "the only topology that can be given is the discrete topology".

Comment: The condition that the topology be Hausdorff is often built into the definition of topological group.  If that is done, a finite group is always discrete.

Comment: @user6312, good point.

Answer (score 4):

If $(G, \tau)$ is a topological group. Then, G is a discrete topological group if $\tau$ is the discrete topology on G.

Answer (score 3):

The term 'discrete' seems to be applied to a topology here.  The unit circle with the euclidean topology is a different topological group from the unit circle with the discretee topology.

Comment: you are saying that they are the same as groups but different as topological spaces? for exmaple the number of path components of $S^1$ is 1 as we can see on a picture but you are saying that we can make it discrete and the circle will have a number of path components that is infinite $|S^1|$?

Comment: @palio: yes. Any set can be given the discrete topology, and any group can be given the discrete topology to make it a discrete group.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the term discrete group can mean different things in different contexts, and in some contexts it can be slightly ambiguous.
(1) If $G$ is a subgroup of a topological group, then being discrete means that $G$ with its subspace topology is discrete.
(2) If not in case (1), but $G$ acts on a metric or topological space $X$, then being discrete means that all the orbits in $X$ are discrete. If some algebraic property of $G$ is being deduced from the action then you probably want the action to be faithful as well.
(3) If no topology or action is mentioned, then discrete likely means finitely generated.

Answer (score 1):

The point here is as I see it that in most of cases, the term is used rather for *subgroups*. We call a subgroup $H$ of a topological group $G$ *discrete* if the induced topology on $H$ is the discrete one. Also, when one refers to a discrete group it very often means that that the group in question is embeddedable naturally in some topological group (whose topology is quite indiscrete) wherein the former group is a discrete subgroup.