# Is $\Bbb Q / \Bbb Z$ discrete?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I would like to say that $\Bbb Q / \Bbb Z$ is not discrete (when $\Bbb Q$ has euclidean topology), since $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb Q$ is not open. But OTOH we have
$$\Bbb Q / \Bbb Z \cong \bigoplus_p \Bbb Q_p / \Bbb Z_p$$ 
which is a direct sum of discrete groups, so it should be a discrete group. Maybe the issue is that the above isomorphism is only as abstract groups, but not as topological groups.

Could anyone confirm/elaborate on this?

Comment: I think you're right, the above isomorphism is only an isomorphism of the underlying group structures.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Q$ with the Euclidean topology is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ with the discrete topology, if the isomorphism only requires to respect the group action and not the topology.

Comment: The completion of the metric space $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}, d(a,b) = \min_n |a-bn|$ is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ while with the discrete metric  $\tilde{d}(a,b) = \sup_p \inf_n |a-b n|_p$ it is complete and $\cong \bigoplus_p \Bbb Q_p / \Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: @reuns Frequently complete and non-complete-metrics on a set $X$ .induce the same topology.

Comment: @PaulFrost For two group-invariant metrics it should be sufficient that the completion are not the same, I should have said that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A non-trival group $G$ can always be endowed with various distinct topologies making it a topological group. Two "universal choices" are the discrete topology and the indiscrete topology. See [What is, exactly, a discrete group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45891/what-is-exactly-a-discrete-group).

However, you consider $G = \Bbb Q / \Bbb Z$ and emphasize that $\Bbb Q$ has the Euclidean topology. In that case the only *reasonable* topology on $G$ will be the quotient topology which is certainly not discrete.

The isomorphism $\Bbb Q / \Bbb Z \cong \bigoplus_p \Bbb Q_p / \Bbb Z_p$ is therefore only an algebraic isomorphism, not an isomorphism of topological groups.

Edited: I just considered which topology is given to an infinite sum $\bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} G_\alpha$ of abelian topological groups. There are various approaches, see for example

Higgins, P. J. "Coproducts of topological Abelian groups." Journal of Algebra 44.1 (1977): 152-159.

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82771298.pdf

Chasco, M. J., and X. Dominguez. "Topologies on the direct sum of topological abelian groups." Topology and its Applications 133.3 (2003): 209-223.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.506.7942&rep=rep1&type=pdf

In my opinion the conclusion is that an infinite sum of discrete abelian topological groups is **not** given the discrete topology. Whether one of the "reasonable" topologies on $\bigoplus_p \Bbb Q_p / \Bbb Z_p$ makes it isomorphic as a topological group to $\Bbb Q / \Bbb Z$ is not known to me.